# return the type of a class instead of an object

Tags: c++, return

I want something like this:

```
class* defineType(ofxDTangible &t) {
    if(t.angle > PI) {
        return STSequencer;
    }
    else if(t.angle > HALF_PI) {
        return STSample;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

So i want to return not an object of the class type but the type of the class itself.
Is it possible?

What i want is something like this:

```
    classType = defineType(tang);
    if(classType != NULL) {
        // create the object somehow?
    }
```

It's probably bad, but i'm just wondering if it's possible.

Comment: What would you like to be able to do with this class?

Comment: made a edit to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, C++ does not have [Reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29).

You can however, use polymorphism to solve this type of problem:

```
class ofxDTangible
{
public:
    float angle;
};

class STbase
{
public:
    virtual ~STBase(){}
};

class STSequencer : public STbase
{
public:
    STSequencer(const ofxDTangible &ofx){ /*...*/ }
};

class STSample : public STbase
{
public:
    STSample(const ofxDTangible &ofx){ /*...*/ }
};

shared_ptr<STbase> defineType(ofxDTangible &t)
{
    if(t.angle > PI) {
        return shared_ptr<STbase>(new STSequencer(t));
    }
    else if(t.angle > HALF_PI) {
        return shared_ptr<STbase>(new STSample(t));
    }
    return shared_ptr<STbase>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get is probably [`std::type_info`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info):

```
const std::type_info* defineType(ofxDTangible &t) {
    if(t.angle > PI) {
        return &typeid(STSequencer);
    }
    else if(t.angle > HALF_PI) {
        return &typeid(STSample);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

although I think this is really weird and you are not describing your real problem.

Comment: Well I think it's my real problem if I would do it like that :)
I was just wondering if it could be any good to separate a piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

you could define a tag to identify the class type:

```
enum class tag { null, sequencer, sample };
tag defineType(ofxDTangible &t) {
  if(t.angle > PI)
    return tag::sequencer;
  if(t.angle > HALF_PI)
    return tag::sample;
  return tag::null;
}
```